# Spagobi correlational parameters or cascading parameters

Tags: parameters, cascading, spagobi

I'm working on spagobi 5.0 where I want to create a chart from two parameters: "idusuario" and "idnrc". Both are a list of values (LOV) from a query selectable for the user. The point is "idnrc" query need the "idusuario" parameter to show the list. I have been searching on the web but I don't find how to set spagobi for do that.

There is a "correlation analitical driver manager" option on the right corner with a "c" icon. Have I to use it? Somebody can tell me how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody helped me :(. I found a solution. The analitical drivers in spagobi can be a list of values from a query. When you use a correlation manager, you don't need to add a parameter into the query (${parameter}), it means, it is not necesary make a filter using a previous parameter directly in the where clause. The correlation property make this for you.

Incorrect query LOV:

```
SELECT id,nrc FROM mdl_user WHERE id = ${idusuario} LIMIT 10
```

Correct query LOV

```
SELECT id,nrc FROM mdl_user LIMIT 10
```

Then you have to configure it on the correlation manager. Check the documentation.